# scrollview xcode4.5 autolayout

Tags: xcode, ios6

-(void)viewDidLoad 
{

[scroller setScrollerEnabled:YES];
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100, 1000)];

[super viewDidLoad];

work 100%  before check auto layout when i check auto layout and add a imagesView,button and more the scroll is dosen't work any more, if I remove autolayout is work good again

Comment: add some code and pls explain more

Comment: If my answer works for you please accept it, If not please add more details so I can help.

Answer (score 5):

To my understanding "autolayout" set constraint after loading the view so the problem could be that you set your constrains on viewDidLoad and just after that "autolayout" changes that.
Try to set this constrains on viewDidAppear.

Comment: Finally someone that figured out the problem. Thank you